# Mongoose child schema (subdocument) is returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

My `teamsSchema` is a child schema within `clientSchema`. The value of `teamName` always returns `undefined`, crashing my backend app when called from Chrome/React.

Oddly, in Postman, the teamName comes back fine. But in React, it returns undefined - and actually crashes my express app because `teamName` is `undefined`. I believe this is because of the Mongoose Schema now allowing it.

Is my Schema set up OK to access this? And why would it be accessible from Postman, but not in Chrome/React? Cheers

```js
const teamsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  teamName: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
  },

  teamMgrs: 
  {
    type: Array,
  },

  teamUsers: 
  {
    type: Array,
  },

  teamID: {
    type: String,
  }
});
```

```js
const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    // generated by UUID
    type: String,
  },
      
  teams: {
    type: Array,
    ref: 'teamsSchema'
  }
});
```

React code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .post(
          `${serverURL}/get-team-name`,
          { teamID: editPrimaryTeam },
  
          {
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include',
          }
        ).then(response => {console.log("teamname", response.data.teamName);})    }, [])
```

Comment: What is your React's code?

Comment: @BlackMath I have added it the question